# Edittext keeps scrolling to its position inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-nestedscrollview, android-textinputedittext

### Prerequisites

**main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="2"
        android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**recyclerview_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <...>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**another_recyclerview_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider_default_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <...>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/anotherRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <...>

</LinearLayout>
```

**edittext_item_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/formTextClearButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <...>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Problem description

I am adding at runtime a `recyclerview_layout.xml` to the `container` inside `main_layout.xml`. The `recyclerview_layout.xml` sometimes contains `another_recyclerview_layout.xml`, which has a `RecyclerView` that has multiple view types, one of which is represented by `edittext_item_layout.xml`. When the latter exists in `another_recyclerview_layout.xml` and `recyclerview_layout.xml` is populated with some other items, the whole layout has a weird scrolling behavior, at the time the user taps on one of the `TextInputEditText`s. It's like it tries to snap to the focused `TextInputEditText` and the user cannot scroll away from that view anymore. (See gif below)

[Scrolling bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t3Ff.gif)

### Already tried solutions

1. Setting `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the direct child of the `NestedScrollView`, as you can already see in `recyclerview_layout.xml`. Also tried to add these properties to all the other containers (cry)
2. Setting `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the parent of `anotherRecyclerView`. This solution does not work weel for me, since I need the `TextInputEditText` to be fully functional.
3. Listening to `SoftKeyboard` events and clearing focus as soon as the keyboard hides. This solution rises 2 other issues:

   - loses scroll position
   - the layout is still buggy, if the user tries to scroll while the keyboard is visible

### Libraries

ConstraintLayout: `2.0.4`

RecyclerView: `1.2.0`

Material: `1.2.1`

### Help!

I am running out of ideas, any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I can't tell why your using it from the example, do you really need the `NestedScrollView` as the parent of the `RecyclerView`? Nested `RecyclerViews` are fine, but `NestedScrollView` as the parent of Nested `RecyclerViews` is definitely asking for trouble.

Comment: It was designed this way, because that particular layout can contain anything, for instance just a simple view, that can have the height bigger than the screen's height and it's not a `RecyclerView`, or a `RecyclerView`. I think refactoring it, so that everything will be held in a `RecyclerView` instead of a `NestedScrollView` would mean a really big refactor.

Comment: Also, adding a `NestedScrollView` is a solution for `SwipeRefreshLayout` with nested `RecyclerView`s problem.